# what does "keep this up" mean in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm reading [this article](https://www.quora.com/How-long-does-it-take-a-car-designer-to-design-a-car/answer/Raghav-Jaswal).

In the last part, the writer uses 'keep this up'

> I look forward to keeping this up.
>   I’d love to keep this up.

What does 'keep this up' mean in this article?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"To keep something up" usually means to keep *something* going, or to continue the action of *something*. In the article, after a *very* quick look around that phrase, the action seems to be "designing cars". In that case, he's saying "I'll keep doing this", or "I will continue designing cars".